# list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, list, google-colaboratory

It said 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'. I am not sure how to fix it. I think there is a large size on the winsor. I have tried to limit it to 0.1, or 0.9 but it does not work. I have no idea how to fix it? Can anyone please help? Many thanks in advance. The image I did attach shows the errors. The error is on the code line : ax2.scatter(x, stats.mstats.winsorize(y, .25)). But I am not sure how to fix it. How to fix it so the code can plot the x and the winsor graph successfully. I have tried to google and find some limits on winsor and when i tried some values it does not work. I have tried to find some of the solutions on stack overflow but it does not show the solution how to fix it on winsor. I am really stuck at the line for the error. The winsor function has the y and the limit at the end. I tried to put limits in the range of (0.1 to 0.9) using the code ax2.scatter(x, stats.mstats.winsorize(y, limits =(0.1, 0.9))) but it does not work. I think the array it too large as the error said The summation method avoids creating a (potentially huge) array. Should I change the code or change the array?

code:

```
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

x = [4 * val for val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
y = [.25 * val for val in x]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax1.scatter(x, y)
ax1.title.set_text('Raw data')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
ax2.scatter(x, stats.mstats.winsorize(y, .25))
ax2.title.set_text('Winsorized data')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
ax3.scatter(x[2:-2], y[2:-2])
ax3.title.set_text('Trimmed data')
ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax3.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax3.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is expecting a Numpy array not a python list. Try `import numpy as np`  and then create y with `y = np.array([.25 * val for val in x])`. You can see this in the docs for [scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html)